# Testing for convergence/proving inequality using a Taylor series.

Tags: integration, solution-verification, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

Given:

$f : \mathbb{R^{+}} \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = \int_{x}^{0}arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}})dt$

Prove that:

for $0<x<1$,

$-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{\pi}{4}x\leq f(x)\leq  \frac{\pi}{4}x$

my progress so far:

I have converted $g(t) :=arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}})$ into a taylor series with 0 as the centre of the approximation and substituted it back into the function so that $f(x) = \int_{x}^{0}T(g;0)dt$. Although I understand the meaning behind this integration, I am having hard time getting to the terms given.

Help or hints would be appreicated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the Taylor series expansion of the function $f(x)$ using the Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: What did you get after using the Taylor expansion?